# Launch Application On Hardware key

Tags: java, android

Can we launch an android application on hardware key press eg long press power key or double tap on power key or volume key. 
I saw some references on internet but didnt find anything regarding double tap or something like that. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.